# Mantaflow use in blender

Tags: mesh, normals, fluid-simulation

[.Blend file](https://pasteall.org/blend/2c0eff3d8d25472b8ed1e6bca69f8e46)

I am a blender beginner and after watching some tutorials online I figured I'd give modeling and animation a try.

I am trying to make an oil hourglass animation that will move the liquid downwards.[The hourglass is exactly the same as the one shown here](https://youtu.be/PZnawGM3l6w?t=207), I have a physical reference of it.

The only issue is that my liquid doesn't seem to want to pass through 2 holes I made on the container mesh, I suspect it's because of the wrong facing normals right outside of it:

[image]

I managed to get the liquid to flow inside of the top sphere.

[image]

but It won't flow into the rest of the mesh.

[image]

Will I have to create a new mesh? Help is appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first thing to note is you need to ensure that your domain resolution is set high enough so you have enough fluid detail to fit through any holes. Look at the small cube in the bottom corner of the domain - visible in your second image; that’s the size of one ‘cell’. Any hole smaller than the width of that will definitely obstruct your flow. Start by increasing the Resolution and/or increasing the size of your ‘holes’.

Also, make sure any obstacle meshes are Manifold (completely enclose a volume).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but unfortunately it seems my liquid is still "stuck"

I increased the resolution divisions to 96 and deleted faces to test out the flow. It made a bit of progress but it still refuses to go down.

https://imgur.com/a/qYPOQef

Comment: That mesh doesn't look manifold. Try adding a Solidify modifier to give the surfaces thickness (that will make it manifold). You might need to 'Apply' the modifier before you re-run the simulation. At the moment, Blender is unable to determine the 'inside' and 'outside' of your obstacle. The simulation uses the obstacle to determine whether each 'cell' is inside or outside the obstacle - those 'inside' are used to exclude the fluid so it's critical that it's manifold so there's a definite 'inside' or 'outside'.

Comment: Haha progress! https://imgur.com/a/wt5ILor

It seems like the flow is behaving a little abnormal in some areas but I think I can figure it out from here. Thank you!